# The method queryForInt(String) is undefined for the type JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to execute a sql query and try to get its value in a integer variable, but I'm getting a compile time error saying

> The method queryForInt(String) is undefined for the type JdbcTemplate

My code is correct I think, so I have problem in my pom file.

my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>sql</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>




    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

my app.java file:

```
package sql.sql;


import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//import org.springframework.jdbc.core;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

//import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //DataSource dataSource = null ;
        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("web.xml");
        DataSource obj = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
         JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(obj);


        String SQL1 = "select count(*) from issues";
        int row1 = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt(SQL1);
        System.out.println(row1);

        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `JdbcTemplate.queryForInt` was [deprecated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForInt%28java.lang.String%29) in Spring 3.2.2 and it was [removed](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html) in Spring 4.2.0.

There is actually a dependency conflict in your `pom.xml`: you depend on Spring version `4.1.0.RELEASE` and `4.2.0.RELEASE` (for `spring-jdbc`). Maven solves that conflict by using version `4.2.0.RELEASE` for all Spring dependencies, so that is why the method `queryForInt` is not available.

You can :

- Downgrade to Spring `4.1.0.RELEASE` for all your dependencies
- Upgrade to Spring `4.2.0.RELEASE` and use instead [`queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) with `Integer.class` as `requiredType`.

I recommend you to upgrade as it is not a good practice to continue using deprecated APIs.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15661313/1743880) for more info.

Comment: i have used 
int count = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL1, Integer.class);

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

There is no such method in Spring JdbcTemplate.

So, your pom is good, you just need to check if you have customized JdbcTemplate to have some overridden methods or you are using a wrong method.

You may want to use the latest method

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

```
 queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, arg1, arg2, ...);
```